# how to deploied on device with data

Tags: gluon-mobile

When I deploie on device the app does not work well because of the data file which is not up. It works well on computer but not on android phone. The app start but only the frame is show up. What is the proper way to do it. I use  xml file because it is convenient. The file is in resources file.

```
      inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dataRU.xml");


      //FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemDisplayName(inputStream);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(CoursFrancais.class);
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        cours = (CoursFrancais) u.unmarshal(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
```

I try also with this code but the file is not found, I guess, because the dataprovider don't return anything.

```
  FileClient file=FileClient.create(new File("//src//main//resources//","dataRU.xml"));

        InputStreamInputConverter<CoursFrancais> converter=new XmlInputConverter<>(CoursFrancais.class);
        GluonObservableObject<CoursFrancais> listePages=DataProvider.retrieveObject(file.createObjectDataReader(converter));
```

Comment: Have you tried `inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("dataRU.xml");`, without the class loader?

Comment: I just tried it but it doesn't work, even on computer. I tried with "//src//main//resources//dataRU.xml" and just "dataRU.xml"

Comment: Of course, that won't work. If your resource is in `src/main/resources/dataRU.xml`, then `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dataRU.xml")` should work.

Comment: Ok it works on desktop but still not working when deployed on device. I am puzzle. What wrong thing I am doing to no be able to just avec data visible on a very simple app.

Comment: You can use `adb logcat -v threadtime` from a terminal, while your phone is plugged and running the app, to find out about any possible exceptions thrown in the process.

Comment: Hi from which terminal  I should used this command?

Comment: Open a terminal (cmd) on your machine, navigate to your ANDROID-SDK `platform-tools` directory and type: `adb logcat -v threadtime`. Else search google on how to use `adb`.